# MongoDb Query: checking if a string contains field value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I know it is possible to check if a field value is like a string like this:

```
db.users.findOne({"username" : {$regex : ".*jo*"}});
```

But what I want is to check if a string contains the filed value.
 If I have a string like this: `"John, Smith, "`, I wanted to match users with username `"John"` and `"Smith"`.

I know it is possible to split the string and use the `$in` operator but wanted to know if it can be done easily using string comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from Mongodb 3.4 they have introduced `$indexOfCP` operator.

> Searches a string for an occurence of a substring and returns the
>   UTF-8 code point index (zero-based) of the first occurence. If the
>   substring is not found, returns -1.

So this works:

```
db.user.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $addFields:
          {
            searchIndex: { $indexOfCP: [ "$username", "John, Smith, " ] },
          }
      },

      { 
        $match: {

             searchIndex: {$ne: -1}

           }
        },
   ]
)
```

and this matches users with username like: "Jo", "John", "Smit", "Smith" ..etc.

Comment: This will return the point index of the first occurnace so wouldn’t satisfy your AND, which is what your OP was asking for.

Comment: Then I have the match statment.

Comment: Ok, I think I must have misunderstood your question :-)

Comment: Isn't the order of elements in `$indexOfCP` array inverted ? The *superstring* should be the first element and *substring* should be second element

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood your question correctly I beleieve the below `$regex` is what you're after.

My collection looks like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a8498a29d1ed018c7f648ca"),
  "name" : "John, Smith, "
}
```

The find and `$regex` looks like :

```
db.foo.find({ name: { $regex: 'John.*Smith' } }, { _id : 0 })
```

If you needed case insensitivity:

```
db.foo.find({ name: { $regex: 'john.*smith', $options: 'i'} }, { _id : 0 })
```

Output:

```
/* 1 */
{
  "name" : "John, Smith, "
}
```

If I was to run:

```
db.foo.find( { name: { $regex: 'Bill.*Smith', $options: 'i' }}, { _id : 0})
```

or

```
db.foo.find( { name: { $regex: 'John.*Bill', $options: 'i' } }, { _id : 0})
```

Output:

```
Fetched 0 record(s) in 1ms
```

So the `$regex` will only return a match if `John` AND `Smith` are in the field.

To elaborate on the actual `$regex` itself:

`.` Matches any single character except the newline character

`*` Matches the preceding expression 0 or more times

`$option` `i` is for case insensitivity

Comment: if you have this data ```{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a8498a29d1ed018c7f648ca"),
  "name" : "John, Smith, "
}``` and you search string is ```JohnSmithBobAlexAlice```, does your query match?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the accepted answer, starting **v3.6** , `$indexOfCP` can be used directly in `find()` via `$expr`

```
db.foo.find({ 
   "$expr": {
       {$ne : [{$indexOfCP: ["John, Smith, ", "$username"]}, -1]}
   }
})
```